# calculate IPV6 range from start ipv6 and end IPv6

Tags: php, ipv6, gmp

i am trying to calculate ipv6 range with the help of gmp library.

> eg: start IP: FE80:CD00:0000:0CDE:1257:0000:211E:729B 
>   end IP: FE80:CD00:0000:0CDE:1257:0000:210D:729E

i have start and end of ipv6 . i want all ip between start and end of ip6.

Comment: Is it on purpose that your start IP is higher than your end IP?

Comment: By mistake i typed start IP in place of end IP and Vice versa.

Comment: For IPv6 your IP _is_ IPv6. There are only two currently used IPs: IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: already corrected

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest foregoing GMP in favour of a pre-made library, for example [S1lentium/IPTools](https://github.com/S1lentium/IPTools).

```
$range = new Range(new IP('FE80:CD00:0000:0CDE:1257:0000:211E:729B'), new IP('FE80:CD00:0000:0CDE:1257:0000:210D:729E'));

foreach($range as $ip) {
    echo (string)$ip . '<br>';
}
```